# CMS encryption on Android 9 and higher

Tags: java, android, cryptography, bouncycastle, x509certificate

Google [announced](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/03/cryptography-changes-in-android-p.html) this year that it's deprecating some functionality from the BC provider. I am using CMS to encrypt the text using a certificate of `X509Certificate` type. However, on Android Pie, I encountered `NoSuchAlgorithmException` as mentioned in the Google post earlier.

> For apps targeting Android P or later, the call will throw
>   NoSuchAlgorithmException.
>
> To resolve this, you should stop specifying a provider and use the
>   default implementation.

I also checked Conscrypt capabilities [here](https://github.com/google/conscrypt/blob/master/CAPABILITIES.md), but couldn't find a way to perform CMS on the text received. Is there any other alternative that can help achieve the same level/type of encryption?

Here's my code:

```
public byte[] encryptText(String txt) {

CMSEnvelopedDataStreamGenerator cmsdataGen = new CMSEnvelopedDataStreamGenerator();
cmsdataGen.addRecipientInfoGenerator(new JceKeyTransRecipientInfoGenerator(deviceCert).setProvider("BC"));
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
OutputStream out = cmsdataGen.open(byteArrayOutputStream, new JceCMSContentEncryptorBuilder(CMSAlgorithm.AES128_CBC).setProvider("BC").build());
byte[] unencryptedContent = txt.getBytes();
out.write(unencryptedContent);
String encrypted = byteArrayOutputStream.toString();
Log.v("Security","ENCRYPTED_STR BEFORE ENCODING= " + encrypted);
out.close();
return byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();

}
```

Comment: Your code is using the bouncycastle API, not the BC provider, presumably you have included the appropriate jars in your project.

Comment: I have included spongycastle libraries for android, although I didn't get the part where you mentioned "I am not using the BC provider"? Line 3 actually sets provider to "BC". Please correct me if I misunderstood. Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't the spongycastle provider use "SC" as its name, not "BC"?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. However, I still need to specify the provider, and as highlighted in my post, Google/Android doesn't like any provider being specified and handle it with default implementation. I am not sure how to achieve that.

Comment: "...Google/Android doesn't like any provider being specified...". No, that note is only about using the built-in BC provider. What happens when you replace "BC" with "SC"?

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I removed 'setProvider' altogether, and the above snippet worked. Thanks again!!